# iPhone Development: What's the difference between an View-Based Application and an Window-Based Application?

Tags: iphone

Like I understand, an Window has a lot of Views. A View is an object that can draw something on the screen, and the Window provides the space for drawing. So where's the point, that I dont have an window? What's the difference here between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the iPhone, a window really is just a special kind of view.  If you look at the docs for the UIWindow class, you'll see that it has additonal methods above and beyond what a regular UIView has.  However, most of those methods seem to have analogous UIView counterparts.

The one thing I've found windows useful for is that UIViews have a "window" property that can be used to instantly access the window.  If you have many nested views and need to immediately get to the top level from a 3rd or 4th level deep view, that window property can come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

In a View based application we can create the foreground layout and the appearance of the application including text fields,buttons,labels..... depending upon the requirements of the project and how effective an application view has to be in order to make the application shine

In a Window based application we have the background of the view and we can also create a view using a window by using Interface Builder connections.But for building applications that work basing on the background we need to have Window based applications that runs on the console.